# One function is not defined when trying to do two function recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, recursion, undefined

I have a page which clients sometimes leave open for extended periods of time without refreshing (over 24hrs).  Some of the actions on that page require valid PHP session so I have built a simple set of functions to run this check every 10 minutes.

**2 Functions:**

1. checkLogin()
2. refreshTimer()

We call checkLogin() to start, checkLogin() calls refreshTimer().  After timer completes it should call checkLogin(), which should call refreshTimer() and start the process all over again.

**The first time we call checkLogin() directly things works great.  However, when refreshTimer() tries to call checkLogin() I get a "function not defined" error for checkLogin().**

From my research it looks like I should be able to call the checkLogin() without passing it to the refreshTimer().

I'm sure I'm probably missing something obvious.  Thanks for your help!

```
function checkLogin()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/mysite.com/dev/includes/check_login_helper.php",
        success: function(logged_in)
        {
            if(logged_in == "false")
            {
                // they are logged out - redirect them to login page
                alert("logged out");
            }
        }
    });
    refreshTimer();
}


function refreshTimer()
{
    var t = setTimeout("checkLogin()",15000); // do each 10 min currently shorter for test
}

//start the process up
checkLogin();
```

**Fixed & using checkInterval**

```
function checkLogin()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/mysite.com/dev/includes/check_login_helper.php",
        success: function(logged_in)
        {
            if(logged_in == "false")
            {
                // they are logged out - redirect them to login page
                alert("logged out");
            }
        }
    });
}


  setInterval(checkLogin(),15000); // do each 10 min currently shorter for test
```

Comment: Actually it might be better to use `var t = setInterval(checkLogin,15000);` here and remove the calls to refreshTimer

Comment: Nice idea, that would simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`; [it's`eval` in disguise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout#Passing_string_literals). There is also no reason to capture the value returned by `setTimeout` in this case.

```
function refreshTimer()
{
    setTimeout(checkLogin, 15000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps explain why.

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = setTimeout("checkLogin()",15000);
```

needs to be

```
var t = setTimeout(checkLogin,15000);
```

this method accepts functions and not strings.

Comment: how would this change explain the behavior? While definitely nicer, it should work either way.

Comment: "This method accepts function handles and not strings" is technically incorrect. The method will accept a string, which is passed to `eval()`.  It is better to use function handles, but not required.

Comment: @BrokenGlass honestly I don't know (would love to learn though).  All I know is that I've always passed functions to setTimeout and setInterval and not strings.

Comment: aha! that's why! evaling the function results in an out of scope call.  "checkLogin()" doesn't exist in the context that the timer is executing.

Comment: @minirobot: So I take it the functions in your sample are in some nested object/namespace?

Comment: @BrokenGlass, the two functions just exist within a standard document.ready page load function: $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: @minirobot then try taking `checkLogin()` outside of the ready function to the same level as the ready function and trying your code with the string

Comment: @Joseph, thanks that also fixes it.  I guess my scope was wrong?

Comment: @minirobot sounds like it. But in any case this was a very edifying discourse. :)